# Why is my Footnotes plugin is not working?

Tags: plugins

I want to add a footnote for the name of the book in the form like;

> It is written in this book^1

So I tried installing two plugins, one [inline footnotes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-footnotes/) plugin and other [easy foonotes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-footnotes/) plugin.

In my editor there are two tabs, visual and text, I see the code like things in text so I go to tex and as directed in plugin instructions I place following code next to where I want to footnote number;

```
 [note]Name of the book[/note]
```

But when I go back to visual nothing happens. The same code shows up as written.

I have installed the plugin using the WordPress installer and also activated.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried publishing the page/post and viewing it on the front end? These are shortcodes, and are only turned into what they're supposed to be on the front-end. In the back-end they'll always appear as shortcodes, regardless of whether you're using Text or Visual mode.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Oopsy... OK my bad...yes it worked that ways...sorry I thought it would show up in visual.